# Small lag spikes using Display.sync, LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I recently started using LWJGL to get into game programming in Java from C#, and I have a basis for the game I am making set up and working, but there is a small problem with lag. The game runs at a constant 60 fps but every few seconds all of the moving entities on the screen will jump a small but noticeable amount. I researched on Google to see if anyone else was having trouble with this, and I found a thread talking about the sync function in Display not being accurate. Is this true? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you also using `Display.setVSyncEnabled([boolean])` ? and does the lag spikes also occur if you don't use `Display.sync([int])` ?

Comment: I tried Display.setVSyncEnabled([boolean]) and it causes more lag.

Comment: Then it's probably your computer that can't handle it. Thereby lag coming from rendering latency.

Comment: My desktop is a higher end gaming computer, but Ill review my drivers and such. I found a forum thread similar to my problem [here](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4449.0).

Comment: What happens if you disable VSync?